# is this code correct about foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

```
String str="insert into subcatag(subcatagid,subcatagory,catagid) values (?,?,select     
catagid from catag where catagory=?)"; 
PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(str);
status=st.executeUpdate();
st.setString(1,v.getSubcatagid());  
st.setString(2,v.getSubCatagory());
st.setString(3,v.getCatagid());
```

where 
    v.getSubcatagid()
    v.getSubCatagory()
    v.getCatagid() all are pojo class methods.. I cannot insert value into database table from JSP inputs. where i go wrong thanks in advance.
my table contains subcatagid int auto_inc primary key, subcatagory varchar(50) not null, and one foreign key column which is catagid from catag table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use Batch Statements in java

Sample Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

//...

Connection connection = new getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

for (Employee employee: employees) {
String query = "insert into employee (name, city) values('"
        + employee.getName() + "','" + employee.getCity + "')";
statement.addBatch(query);
}
statement.executeBatch();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

May be this link will help

[Batch statement](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)